# Missing following extensions: 'gd' 'mcrypt' 'intl' 'mbstring' 'zip'

Tags: magento2

I am installing **magento 2.1.6** on **ubuntu 16.04**, when i install it via command line, it shows me the following information:
Missing following extensions: 'gd' 'mcrypt' 'intl' 'mbstring' 'zip'

What's happened and what should i do?

Other info:
mysql 5.7 installed
PHP 7.0.15 installed
Apache 2.4 installed

Zip is actually installed already.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After u done installing the php run the below command to install all the php extensions required in magento2.

```
sudo apt-get -y install php-fpm php-cli php-gd php-imagick php-mysql php-mcrypt php-pear php-curl php-intl php-xsl php-zip php-mbstring
```

Hope this will help.